# Images from Amazon S3 CORS not working in Chrome

Tags: angularjs, amazon-s3, kendo-ui, cors, export-to-pdf

I'm using Kendo UI to draw and export PDF the DOM of my HTML page, but only in Firefox works fine. I have tried configure the CORS of amazon S3 without success.

In the screen, the image is displayed without problem

This is the error that I get:

```
Image from origin 'http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Amazon S3 CORS configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

The problem is in this part of my HTML:

```
<img id="imgSearch"
ng-src="{{person.company.PrincipalLogo}}">
```

where the variable `person.company.PrincipalLogo` has this value: `http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/decision-dis/DCGS/empresaContratante/1723646632001_LogoDCA.png`

Even I have tried with `src` instead of `ng-src`, but nothing.

The method to export PDF is:

```
$scope.exportarPDF = function () {

            kendo.drawing.drawDOM("#idDiv", {
                paperSize: "A4",
                margin: "1cm",
            }).then(function (group) {
                kendo.drawing.pdf.saveAs(group, "report.pdf");
            });
        };
```

Needless to say the image is inside the `<div id="idDiv"></div>`

Comment: Any solution? Having same problem